# How do I install from Maven Central?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to install this but I'm unfamiliar with Maven and I have no idea how to follow the installation instructions: https://github.com/twosigma/flint
(it's one of those "so basic nobody bothers to state it on the internet" questions)

According to that link "Scala artifact is published in maven central" - so how do I get that thing installed where Spark (and ultimately pyspark) can use it?

For apt it would just be `apt-get install xyz`
For pip it would just be `pip install xyz`

so why isn't `mvn install flint` working for me?

Answer (score 2):

Add the [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twosigma/flint/0.6.0) to your Maven project's `pom.xml` (if you have a project):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twosigma</groupId>
    <artifactId>flint</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or download the [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/twosigma/flint/0.6.0/flint-0.6.0.jar) (linked from the above link) or from [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.twosigma/flint/0.6.0/jar) (click "Browse" or "Downloads").

I don't know Spark or Scala. Maybe there is more convenient way to get it via dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that you do not install Maven dependencies.

You just add them to your `pom.xml` (when doing Maven) or the appropriate build file (e.g. `build.gradle`). Then they are downloaded automatically from MavenCentral (or any other configured repository), as soon as you build.

For the "How do I add them", I refer to the answer of @Freddy.

Comment: Thank you - I wish to use the library in pyspark REPL. I therefore need to build it and have it inserted into my system such that "import sparkts" in the REPL would find the library.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you. I can tell you how to use the library if you build your project with Maven or Gradle, sbt should also work. What do you use to build your project?

Comment: The pyspark REPL is an interpreter command line for Spark. Flint is a library for doing time series stuff on Spark data. If I wanted to do math stuff in the normal Python (or Ipython) REPL but I didn't have numpy for example, I could just do "pip install numpy" and hey presto, next time I type "import numpy" into the Python REPL it knows what I mean and renders the library available to me. If the library were not available in an online repo like numpy but rather in a file, I could do "pip install /path/to/file" for the same. I have the Flint files. I want it available to me in the pyspark REPL

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with that. I don't know how pyspark REPL tries to resolve Maven dependencies and furthermore, I do not know how you provide pyspark REPL with the appropriate coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In the corporate world you would need to find your Maven proxy's `repository_url`,  ask for Nexus or Artifactory with the Java developers.

Then know that you can install all kinds of jvm software published in Maven Central and other configured repositories without using Maven, or Java. As long as you know the Maven properties of the application artifacts.

You can use this in an Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Download application_artifact to the apps directory
  maven_artifact:
    group_id: "{{ app_group_id }}"
    version: "{{ application_artifact.version }}"
    artifact_id: "{{ application_artifact.artifact_id }}"
    repository_url: "{{ repository_url }}"
    extension: "{{ application_artifact.type }}"
    dest: "{{ server_dir }}/apps"
    owner: "{{ app_account }}"
    group: "{{ app_group }}"
    mode: 0755
```